# ¿Cómo imprimir una coma en un csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, csv, filewriter

estoy tratando de imprimir una fórmula de excel en un archivo csv desde python 3. Necesito imprimir lo siguiente:

`venta_anterior='=BUSCARV(A2,"C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\[productos_de_{}_fecha_{}.csv]productos_de_{}_fecha_{}"!$A:$A,4,0)'.format(id_vendedor,fecha_ayer,id_vendedor,fecha_hoy)`

Sin embargo, en todas las comas, el interprete de csv me las toma como un separador de columna, y yo obviamente quiero que se tome todo como un solo texto. Intenté usar backslash sin éxito. 
Será que mi única opción es cambiar el caracter separador?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "el intérprete"?

Comment: Hola Gerardo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Para poder darte una respuesta adecuada es necesario que expliques bien que quieres hacer y proveas un [mcve] con una entrada y salida esperadas. Sería oportuno que nos mostraras unas cuantas líneas del csv y el código que usas para leerlo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas comas como separador de campos en CSV, entonces la forma de poder introducir una coma en un campo consiste en delimitar dicho campo por comillas.

Por ejemplo, la siguiente sería una línea válida dentro de un CSV delimitado por comas:

```
n,nombre,comentario,edad
1,Alvaro,Esta cadena no tiene comas,25
2,Ramon,"Esta cadena, si tiene comas", 22
```

De todas formas no entiendo si en tu pregunta estás tratando de generar un CSV (en cuyo caso mi respuesta es pertinente), o estás tratando de leerlo, en cuyo caso sería mejor que usaras alguna biblioteca de lectura de CSVs, como la que viene en el propio python ([módulo `csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html)), que tiene en cuenta diferentes delimitadores, casos especiales, etc.

En general, incluso para escribirlo, puede ser más conveniente que uses dicho módulo, ya que él se ocupará automáticamente de añadir las comillas donde sean necesarias, o de "escaparlas" si el valor en cuestión, además de coma, tenía comillas.

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217/342)

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Gracias por explicar tu voto, no estabas obligado. De todas formas, ya que explicas la razón, aprovecho para decir que no estoy de acuerdo del todo. La pregunta era "¿Cómo imprimir una coma en un csv?" y eso está contestado. Aún me quedaba la duda de si el problema era para leer o para escribir, y por eso en mi respuesta incluí detalles para ambos casos. Bajo mi punto de vista, aunque respondí cuando la pregunta no era aún clara del todo, la respuesta sí que cubre las dos posibles interpretaciones de la pregunta.

Comment: Sí los cubre, de hecho así lo terminé haciendo. Muchas gracias por la respuesta :)